# How to install Ubuntu using the efi shell

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu

Is there a way to install Ubuntu using the efi shell.
Since I can't find the `boot mode` in my BIOS

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu uses grub-efi for UEFI systems. So what you really want to load from EFI shell is GRUB.

This should be EFI/grub/grubx64.efi

Type mount for detected storage devices:

```
mount
```

This will only tell you basic information about PCI bus location bus type (SATA), device type (HD, usb etc) and partition type (GPT). Try to guess your disk. If you get it wrong thats okay you'll confirm in the next step.

```
mount blk1
fs0:
ls
```

That mounts the file system of the first devices first partition and prints the files. The file list should contain "EFI" if it does proceed otherwise try other blks.

Try

```
ls EFI\grub
```

and confirm grub is present. Sometimes its incorrectly in BOOT.

```
ls EFI\Boot
```

and check for grubx64.efi

Once you've found the file simply start it.

```
EFI\grub\grubx64.efi
```

Press enter. If you have secure boot then you should be looking for the file shim.efi and do the same thing. Otherwise you'll need to add grubx64.efi to the allowed executables in SecureBoot.

Comment: If an external drive, the UEFI path is always /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. But the actual file bootx64.efi may be a copy of grub/shim customized for installer, full grub or shim from a full install, or a Windows efi file to boot Windows installer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I followed the directions, not having a geek->human translator, and after I couldn't find anything with EFI in the UEFI shell, I typed exit, hit enter, and then things booted up as they should have. This should be put into the guide. Just saying.

4% to go...never mind, no errors found. this is real time. I have a spinning thing with ubuntu on the screen. now the spinning thing is gone and ubuntu is on the bottom. just looked again, there is a small spinning thing in the bottom right corner.

Now there is a gradient from pink-deep purple screen with what appears to be a line etching of a panther. holy shit, i think I did it.
Moral of the story, open UEFI shell, type mount, hit enter. Type mount [disk blk name] (ex, mine showed up as blk0) Before you go into the uefi shell from the boot menu, move the highlighted line over your usb and write down the name and details. That will make things a lot easier than guessing your drive name. after that, type fs0. you will get a weird line of text. then type ls. Once the other error[?] message shows up, give up and type exit, then hit the enter key. The system will install as normal, for whatever reason.