# Unable to boot from USB to install Ubuntu after Windows10?

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, windows-10

I have 3 days trying to install Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20 in dual boot. I researched and found that windows should be installed first and then Linux. I already asked in Super User forum and tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/981267/1099038) answer too without success

I already have Windows 10 installed in BIOS mode = UEFI.

I have BIOS with UEFI enabled.

I created a bootable USB using Rufus from an Ubuntu iso file with the following parameters

- GPT and UEFI (non CSM)
- FAT32.

Now, when I try to boot from bootable USB, appears a yellow shell that I found is named EFI shell and I'm stuck in how to fix this.

Note: In case it matters, the motherboard is American Megatrends a kind of old.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you disable secure boot in UEFI?

Comment: @Raffles Hi, I don't find that option in the BIOS and I followed a way to disable secure boot from Windows and doesn't appear either. I'm not sure what other workaround to try

Comment: @Raffles I've just tried to make a bootable USB with Rufus using a Puppy Linux iso named `bionicpup64-8.0-uefi.iso` with parameters GPT, EUFI and FAT32 and I got the installation menu of Puppy Linux. Then I tried to do the same process with the Ubuntu iso `ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` but with Ubuntu bootable USB boots directly on Windows10. What could be different between puppy Linux iso and Ubuntu iso?

Comment: I suggest to follow the guide [here](https://www.pcsteps.com/3305-prepare-windows-dual-boot-installation/) and then follow the steps [here](https://www.pcsteps.com/961-install-ubuntu-linux-windows/). Ubuntu 20.04.1 will be the same steps as 17.04

Comment: @Raffles thanks for your help. Now I've tried with Unetbootin with same ISO and install menu appears, but when I select install get stuck in a black screen. I'm not sure if would be better format disk, install first Ubuntu and then install Windows?

Comment: You can format the disk into two partitions, re-install Windows in the first partition, and then install Ubuntu in the second partition. Pay attention to the correct formats. I suspect you won't achieve dual-boot if you install Ubuntu first, as the Ubuntu installer knows what to do if Windows is present on the disk, but not vice-versa. Or you can simply re-format the partitions with GParted on which you had Puppy installed, maybe there is something there which is preventing Ubuntu from installing.

Comment: @Raffles Thanks for your help. Testing and testing I was able to install Elementary OS. Any flavour of Ubuntu fails. Elementary OS is based on Ubuntu I think but it works I don't know why.